# Q: Why does [Code]:guard name() else{ throw }, show "Missing argument parameter #1in call swift 2 xcode 7

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift2, xcode7

[image: Here is the error]
[image: Here is the Declared function isValidBirth]

Why is it showing me Error: "Missing argument parameter #1 in call"?

Comment: well, `isValidBirth()` takes a string argument...

Comment: Add your code as text, not image.

Comment: Thank you @vacawama 

And thank you to the one who downgraded my post, it truly shows how much faith we have in humanity. It simply states how bad I'm at programming when I have such a low level of error to comprehend. At least you gave me the kindness to look this way just so you could spit on my face for no reason, thank you!

Comment: You're not using `str` in `isValidBirth()` so you should probably just change it to `func isValidBirth() -> Bool {`.

Comment: I fixed it with `guard isValidBirth(birthField!) else
{
   throw Error.InvalidBirth
}
`

Comment: You were downvoted because it was not a good question. Even a perfect answer to your question isn't going to help anyone else reading this site. Parameter #1 in your function call was missing, the compiler told you so, and you asked why. Because it was missing. Bad question.

Comment: I'm sorry I disappointed you. I hope by downvoting me you can feel happy again, and start roaming the site once more to find other people to bother. gl & hf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method `isValidBirth` expects an argument. You need to pass a value to that method, so change your code like:

```
guard isValidBirth(birthField) else
{
   throw Error.InvalidBirth
}
```

Comment: Yes, I'm so stupid....

it's more like  = guard isValidBirth(birthField!) else { throw Error.InvalidBirth}